# Почему 1С-Битрикс не использует jquery?

Tags: jquery, битрикс

Почему разработчики 1С-Битрикс не стали использовать jquery?

Как это связано с лицензией?

Comment: В 11 версии jquery включена в ядро:


    <?
      CJSCore::Init(array("jquery"));
    ?>

Answer (score 1):

Наверное потому, что когда была представлена *JQuery* (2006 год) *битрикс* был уже 5 версии.

Так исторически сложилось.

А лицензия не причем. У *JQuery*,  *MIT* лицензия позволяет вообще все что угодно.